# Audio Libraries for MP3 editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, mp3

In one o f my projects using ASP.NET + C# I want to be able to dynamically create 30 seconds clip of MP3 files and add a fade in/out.

What library would you recommend?

I saw there are a lot, including:

> http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx
>
> http://www.audiosoundeditor.com/
>
> http://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html

Have you ever had to deal this? What library worked the best for you?

Anything will help including free/priced software that I could call from my C# application or any kind of C# compatible library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) - There would be a bit of programming required to do this but basically it would be along the lines of using NAudio to decode the MP3 first. Then passing the wave file to fade in (turn up the volume) at the time required and fade out (turn down the volume) when required. If your going to pass this to a client in a format other than wave you would then need to re-encode this file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `winmm.dll` library.

Comment: do you have more information regarding this?

Comment: Take a look ->
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Audio_Player__with_Winmm.aspx

Regards

Comment: Can this do fading/croping ? It doesn't look like it

Comment: This is the link to the reference guide:
 http://www.webtropy.com/articles/art9-2.asp?lib=winmm.dll
If you can adapt this to your needs,it's ok... But you must write some code, to control volume and time to play.

 Regards,
  RG

Answer (score 1):

There is a better option, that would be the BASS Library. http://un4seen.com/bass.html it has a dedicated forum and does DSP like fade/compressor/EQ, etc. Plus you can read a bunch of different audio formats. It has C# and vb.net support.

Comment: Thanks. It looks nice, but it's really expensive!

Comment: It's like $100 or less. not too bad. Plus it does a lot of cool sh#t!

Comment: If it's just for private use, the library is free. (Don't know if your project is commercial or not)