# Create 30 second preview of an MP3 file

Tags: asp.net, audio, mp3, asp.net-3.5, preview

I'm looking for a way of automatically creating a 30 second preview file of an MP3 when it is uploaded through my ASP.NET Web Application.

I want this to work similar to [last.fm](http://last.fm) or iTunes where you can preview a 30 second clip of an MP3 file before purchasing and downloading the entire song.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Alvas.Audio](http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx).  It's a .net library that allows you to do all sorts of things with mp3s.  You could use it to chop of a portion of the mp3 and create a new 'thumbnail' mp3 that your site could use for previewing.

There is also [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) that is free and could do what you need.

EDIT: A quick search came up with this similar question on SO that you might want to check out:
[Audio Libraries for MP3 editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922644/audio-libraries-for-mp3-editing)