# How to create 30 seconds clips of .mp3 files in C# on desktop client software?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, wav, audio-converter

I wanted to find out if there is a way to create 30 second clips (with a start time in seconds) of .wav or .mp3 files in C# (or using a C# library).  Most of the code or libraries I've seen seem related to recording and playback, but what if you just want to do processing of an action like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google: c# create mp3 clips

Hit #1 is your question

Hit #2 is: [Audio Libraries for MP3 editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922644/audio-libraries-for-mp3-editing) asking specifically "to be able to dynamically create 30 seconds clip of MP3 files"

Comment: Ok, these seem heavy handed but I'll look at them.