# C# change bass of a mp3 or wav song

Tags: c#, mp3, wav

Is there a public song editing class for C#, I just want to be able to change the bass of a song quickly.
Any information will be helpful.

Comment: Some sort of equalizer library?

Comment: @RitchMelton to be fair, for many years I didn't know that "bass" was pronounced like "base" when it's referring to the music definition and I thought that "bass" and "base" were 2 separate music terms.

Answer (score 2):

"Changing the bass" (reducing, removing, or increasing it) can be accomplished with a high-pass filter, amplitude change + low pass filter, or equalizer/"graphic equalizer".

They're all forms of the same basic concept.  See [the Wikipedia article on audio Equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_%28audio%29)

And see this question for a list of MP3 audio manipulation libs in C#:

[Audio Libraries for MP3 editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922644/audio-libraries-for-mp3-editing)