# .NET libraries for editing audio

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

I'm going to create a small .NET desktop application in order to edit some audio files (preferably mp3 or wave files). I want something like WavePad, so that users can load a file and select desired parts and create new files from these parts. What are my options? Is there any .NET library providing these features?

Answer (score 5):

There is a Library Called [Naudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

Comment: Yes I've seen Naudio, do you know how is it possible with Naudio?

Answer (score 3):

check this SO links :

***[Audio Libraries for MP3 editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922644/audio-libraries-for-mp3-editing)***

may be this will help you.